# Android FragmentManager: getBackStackEntryCount() and popBackStack()

Tags: android

I have a method to remove all backstack

```
public void removeAllInBackStack(FragmentManager fm) {
    int len = fm.getBackStackEntryCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        fm.popBackStack(null,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

But when I run it.
Value of len is always > 0 , but popBackStack have java.lang.NullPointerException.

I tried width popBackStack() and popBackStack(id,FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE).

This is logcat:

```
android.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:676)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1496)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$3.run(FragmentManager.java:464)
    android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1401)
    android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5076)
    android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2566)
    android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2604)
    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4747)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to do the same thing in my app, here is how I did it :

```
try {
     fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
     fm.executePendingTransactions();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Dianne Hackborn explain the correct method to do that in this post :
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/0qXCA9rW7EI

As explained in the link : popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); is supposed to pop the entire back stack.

Comment: After one hour of searching,  your solution was the first one with the line "fm.executePendingTransactions" which helped me to clean the backstack to the size of 0. Thank you! :)